# Why does it occur segmentation fault when using the return value of function gets()?

Tags: c

If successful, the `gets` function returns its argument. But when I use the return value in `printf`, it occurs segmentation fault. The code that occurs error is below.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
 
#define MAX_LINE 100
 
int main(void)
{
   char line[MAX_LINE];
   char *result;
 
   printf("Please enter a string:\n");
   if ((result = gets(line)) != NULL)
      printf("The string is: %s\n", result); // Segmentation fault.
   else if (ferror(stdin))
      perror("Error");
}
/*** output ***
Please enter a string:
abc
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
*/
```

But if I use the argument of the `gets` function to print input, the error goes away.

```
      /* -- snip -- */
      printf("The string is: %s\n", line); // correct
```

In the case of the `fgets` function, there is no error when using the return value. Below is the `fgets` function code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define  MAX_LEN  100
 
int main(void)
{
   FILE *stream;
   char line[MAX_LEN], *result;
 
   stream = fopen("mylib/myfile","rb");
 
   if ((result = fgets(line,MAX_LEN,stream)) != NULL)
      printf("The string is %s\n", result); // correct
 
   if (fclose(stream))
      perror("fclose error");
}
```

If successful both function `gets` and `fgets`, both functions return the first argument `char *str`. Why would segmentation fault happen only in the `gets` function?

Above code is from https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-gets-read-line and https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-fgets-read-string#fgets

My environment is gcc 8.4.0.

Below is a warning message.

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’; did you mean ‘fgets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if ((result = gets(line)) != NULL)
                  ^~~~
                  fgets
test.c:11:16: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    if ((result = gets(line)) != NULL)
                ^
/tmp/ccuOAqAp.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x30): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
(base) sh@sh-550P5C-550P7C:~/exercises/dummies/cpp$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’; did you mean ‘fgets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if ((result = gets(line)) != NULL)
                  ^~~~
                  fgets
test.c:11:16: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    if ((result = gets(line)) != NULL)
                ^
/tmp/ccQIks7u.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x30): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

Comment: Did you get any warnings when you compiled the code?

Comment: Never use `gets`, it is no longer part of the standard C library. Please read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets` has been removed from the C11 standard. Unfortunately the way it is implemented can cause the exact problem in this question. The `gets` declaration was removed from the `stdio.h` header but the definition/implementation is still present in libc. That's essentially what this warning is telling you (and illustrates why you should never ignore warnings):

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’; did you mean ‘fgets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if ((result = gets(line)) != NULL)
```

For implicit declarations C assumes the function returns `int`. But in this case the function actually returns `char *`. For a 64 bit binary `int` is 32 bit and `char *` is 64 bit. Hence the return value will be incorrectly truncated and result in a seg fault when the invalid address is accessed.

The bottom line - don't use `gets`. Use `fgets` instead. See: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

If you really must use `gets` then the workaround is to compile with `-std=c99` or manually declare `gets` prototype.